# Capture output of bash code run in python

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess, stdout

I'm trying to capture the output of a bash line I'm executing in my python script using the following code:

```
call_bash = subprocess.Popen(['/space/jazz/1/users/gwarner/test.sh'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = call_bash.communicate()[0]
```

This works fine but I'd like to change it so that that bash code is written directly into this python script (eliminating the need for a separate .sh file). I know that I can run bash code from python with `subprocess.call()` but I can't figure out how to capture the output (what normally gets printed to the terminal incase I'm using the wrong terminology). Can anyone help?

I'm running python 2.7 on CentOS

Comment: Whats your bash file look like? How can we help merge the shell script into a python script if we don't know what it is?

Comment: @heinst i think he is asking for general solution. op wants to embed bash script in python script directly, while execute it as a bash script alone

Comment: @heinst `ssh me@cli.globusonline.org scp me#comp:/~/blah.text ep#comp:/register/`

This is the script though the answer should be the same regardless of what it is. I'm asking about executing bash code in python and retrieving it's output.

Comment: @GWarner with my tests, if you do `print output` it should contain the output of the shell script

Comment: @heinst Yes, but what I'm asking is how do I change this code so that that actual bash code is in the python script as opposed to a seperate .sh file. I'm looking for something like:

`call_bash = subprocess.Popen(['ssh me@cli.globusonline.org scp me#comp:/~/blah.text ep#comp:/register/'],stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`
`output = call_bash.communicate()[0]`
`print output`

Comment: basically you will need `pexpect` and run `bash` in side, then send the bash script text into it line by line. it can't be better than that

Comment: Try Andrew Moffat's sh module (pip install sh).  The docs are at http://amoffat.github.io/sh/ and the dev github is at https://github.com/amoffat/sh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to [subprocess.Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) is a list of arguments (unless you specify `shell=True`).

So you could do your example like

```
call_bash = subprocess.Popen(['ssh', 'me@cli.globusonline.org', 'scp me#comp:/~/blah.text ep#comp:/register/'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = call_bash.communicate()[0]
```

This will invoke the `ssh` command with 2 arguments, `me@cli.globusonline.org` and `scp me#comp:/~/blah.text ep#comp:/register/`.

Comment: They asked how to run that command without using an external script, what part of my answer does not satisfy that question?